# RTP Packets video extraction

Tags: qt, sockets, camera, h.264, rtp

I made use of a QTcpSocket to receive RTP Packets on a socket.
I am receiving a H264 compressed video.
I have written an algorithm to seperate the payloads.
Now how can I view my view my code using these payloads. 
- Do I need to save them in a file? If yes, then what should the format be? 
- Is it possible to view video through QMediaPlayer?
- Do I need to add 4 bytes NAL data before every payload?

Thanks.